# CSS - leaving enough horizontal space for text wrapping around image

Tags: html, css, image, word-wrap

I want to show an image and a text around it. The problem is that I don't know image size in advance. I don't want to scale image up. It is ok to scale image down.
I want image to take maximum space no larger then 100%.
So the following situations are fine

```
1.
--------------------------
[  IMAGE            100% ]
Text Text Text Text TExt T
ext Text Text Text Text Te

2.
--------------------------
Text Text  [ IMAGE   50% ]
Text Text Text Text TExt T
ext Text Text Text Text Te

3.
--------------------------
Text Text Text T [ IMAGE ]
ext Text Text Text TExt Te
xt Text Text Text Text Tex
```

In 1. Image is scaled down to full width. In 2. to Half width. in 3 it is natural image size.

I don't have solution, so I resided to leaving case 1. out, 
and setting image's `max-width: 50%;`

```
       .myimage{
            max-width: 50%;
            max-height: 200px;
            float: right;
            height: auto;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

If I set `max-width: 100%;` I sometimes get images native size being about 80% of the width and then too little horizontal space is left for text and this looks ugly.

If it is impossible with just CSS, how would you do it with JavaScript?

What I do right now is to set image's max-width to 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VUYHZ/2/

Hope you are looking for the same